# What does "UOPI" on a US passport stamp mean?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

A US immigration officer wrote "UOPI" on my passport. He suspected that I wasn't actually visiting the country for tourism but intending to work there.

What does this term mean:

[image]

Comment: You were still admitted though?
Were you attempting to etner on a visa or the VWP?

Comment: Could you take a photo that's in focus?

Comment: I think it says 'O OF I' (O of I) if that's of any use.

Comment: I think what comes after U of I is more important.

Comment: Please don't shrink your images or take them in a portrait orientation. It just makes them hard to read.

Comment: It looks like you were admitted for a month instead of the standard 90 days, which is unusual. I wonder if this is relevant.

Comment: Just registered ... Attempting to enter on a visa. Yes, I just left for home today, after a 30 period stay in the US.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the orientation doesn't make the image hard to read. It's the blurriness caused by the motion of the camera and/or subject during the exposure.

Comment: U of I - Unsure of Intent? ...

Comment: Please post a legible photograph: the current one is impossible to read.

Comment: Why has this question been closed?

Comment: @nikhil This question has been closed because the photograph is hard to read. We would like a legible one. Also, questions have been asked in the comment section but not answered.

Comment: @Jan I asked because this was linked to another question, and couldn't find any other info on the net about this either, maybe the two questions could be merged and answered, so as to help anyone in the future with the same query.