# Will I be allowed to re-enter the US on my B2 Visa?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports

An immigration officer suspected that I was entering the US to work (although I was really entering the country as a tourist). He wrote the following into my passport and told me that I'd need to leave the country after 30 days, which I complied with.

What does his writing (black and on the left) mean? I suspect that it either says UOPI or UOFI -- if I am allowed to re-enter the US in the future on my B-2 visa, what steps can I take to make sure that, next time, I'm not suspected of entering to work?

[What does "UOPI" on a US passport stamp mean?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68573/what-does-uopi-on-a-us-passport-stamp-mean)

[image]

Comment: It's most likely that @Berwyn came closest when [you asked as another user](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68573/what-does-uopi-on-a-us-passport-stamp-mean) to which you've linked: Unsure Of Person's Intent

Comment: @pnuts while this concerns the same passport stamp, the question is different ("will they let me in next time" vs. "what does the stamp mean").

Comment: Bhai: Have you tried looking up your I-94 record [online](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/)?  It's possible that there might be some clue there, though I wouldn't think it likely.

Comment: Bhai: "Unless specifically authorized by a supervisory inspector, the 
admission period shall be no less than 6 months": it's possible that the notation indicates who authorized your shortened period of admission, rather than the reason.

Comment: @pnuts There is a Q buried there, how to smooth his next entry so that his visit is not limited and that the purpose is not challenged at the border. Unsure Of Persons Intent may have been the result OP's response to questions posed by CBP.

Answer (score 4):

The notation on your admission stamp does not invalidate your visa. If they wanted to do that, they would have written or stamped *CANCELLED* on the visa itself.

The fact that they suspected you of traveling to the US to work suggests that the 30-day period of admission was probationary. Since you complied with the terms of your admission (I assume), you are perhaps more likely to be admitted on subsequent attempts rather than less.